# Inserting +1.7976931348623155E308 into column ORA-01426 numeric overflow

Tags: ora-01426

I am porting an application that used a large Java double value (MAX-1d = +1.7976931348623155E308) as a semaphore to indicate a condition. I can not figure out how to define the column to accept this value without yielding the error: ORA-01426: numeric overflow. I have tried various precisions of FLOAT (up through 126), and DOUBLE_PRECISION and BINARY_DOUBLE, and tried a trigger to use TO_BINARY_DOUBLE -- all failed. I am using 11g. DB2 accepts DOUBLE as a datatype and processes this value.

```
-- DDL for Table TEST (generated from specifying BINARY_DOUBLE for COLUMN1)

CREATE TABLE "DB2ADMIN"."TEST"
( "COLUMN1" BINARY_DOUBLE
) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "SYSTEM" ;

insert into test (column1) values (+1.7976931348623155E308);
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01426: numeric overflow
```

Comment: Porting is from DB2 v9.7 to Oracle 11g

Answer (score 1):

Evidently, I need to use a string conversion to binary double for this to work:

SQL> insert into test (column1) values (to_binary_double('1.7976931348623155E308'));

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test where column1 = (to_binary_double('1.7976931348623155E308'));

COLUMN1
1.798E+308

SQL> delete from test where column1 > 0;

1 row deleted.